# Extract Bulleted Text From Powerpoint

Tags: c#, vba, powerpoint, office-interop

I am trying to extract bulleted text from powerpoint slides. But I couldn't find any helpful function which can provide information about if current line is in bullet list or not. I tried identifying it using indent level, but I dont find it useful either.

For example:

If slide contains text like:

```
Abcdefg...
. B
. C
  . D
     .E
```

In this, there are 5 paragraphs, if get indent level of each paragraph it will come as :

```
Paragraph   IndentLevel
Abcdefg...   1
B            1
C            1
D            2
E            3
```

Here, first 3 paragraph have same indent level, but only B and C are in bulleted list, so my program should B, c, D, E.

Here, i dont have any way to figure out if this para starts with bullet or not.

Can you please help?

Thanks,
Kailas

## Edit:

Code that I am using for retrieving text

```
public void analyzeText( PowerPoint.Shape shape )
{
    if( shape.HasTextFrame == Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue && shape.TextFrame.HasText == Office.MsoTriState.msoTrue )
    {
        PowerPoint.TextRange textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
        string text = textRange.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(text);
        for( int i=1; i<=textRange.Paragraphs().Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paragram COunt : " + textRange.Paragraphs(i).Text + " Indent " + textRange.Paragraphs(i).IndentLevel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you currently using to pull the text out? Some sample code may be useful.

Comment: Added code I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks JamieG for helping out. Your answer gave me hint. Here is how I was able to solve this problem:

```
 PowerPoint.BulletFormat bulletFormat = textRange.Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat.Bullet;

    if( bulletFormat.Type == PowerPoint.PpBulletType.ppBulletNone )
                           // Not Bulleted
    else
                        // Bulleted
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method to establish if the paragraph is bulleted or not:

```
blnBullet = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs(x).ParagraphFormat.Bullet
```